# How to use simple hello world example on opa server

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have defined a file with name - play.rego

```
package play
default hello = false

hello {
  m := input.message
  m == "world"
}
```

I also have file called -input.json

```
{ "message": "world"}
```

I now want to use the policy to evaluate on input data using opa server -

opa run --server

I also then registered the policy using below command -

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8181/v1/policies/play --data-binary @play.rego
```

and then I run below command for evaluating policy on the query -

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8181/v1/policies/v1/data/play --data-binary '{"message": "world"}'
```

But the server always responds with nothing.
I need help fixing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the second request is wrong (should not contain `v1/policies`), and the `v1` API requires you to wrap the `input` document inside an `input` attribute. Try:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8181/v1/data/play --data-binary '{"input":{"message": "world"}}'`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Also I realized that when I curl -X GET http://localhost:8181/v1/policies/play , I get this response -> {
  "code": "resource_not_found",
  "message": "storage_not_found_error: policy id \"play\""
}

Comment: I realized if I start opa server on the folder containing policy with following command  -> "opa run --server ." then it loads the policy correctly and it works. But when I CURL POST the policy then it doesn't. I think there is a bug in OPA.

Comment: You have an error in your policy. m := "world" Should be m == "world"

Comment: Thank you with all the changes you suggested it works fine